# EF Core - In Memory Database - HasDefaultValue is being ignored

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

I am running into an issue where I try to add a default value for a few columns. However in my integration tests even though my model is setup in following way:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(x => x.Idx).HasDefaultValue(Guid.NewGuid());
```

the default value is being ignored and I always end up with an empty GUID.

Is there any way how elegantly solve the default valuel for In Memory Database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.HasValueGenerator<T>()` did the trick for me.

In my case it would be:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(x => x.Idx).HasValueGenerator<GuidValueGenerator>();
```